# How can I get Places > Connect to server... to default to SSH rather then FTP

Tags: nautilus, ssh, package-management

I often use Places > Connect to server... and always connect with SSH.

The Connect to Server dialog box always selects Service type as Public FTP by default.

Is there a way to change this so Service type always defaults to SSH?

Comment: Pavlos Gs answer should be helpful. But I think you could actually file this as a bug, since ssh is much more relevant than ftp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any relevant parameter, config file or gconf setting available in order to change the default options, so i guess you'll have to recompile the `nautilus` package.

You should download the [source package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/gutsy/+package/nautilus) first and probably edit `/src/nautilus-connect-server-dialog.c`.

More info on how to compile nautilus can be found on the following links:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1049716

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1678656

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Pavlos G. for the info and links. After reading the links and a few more Google searches I recompiled with the following:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep nautilus # get build dependencies 
apt-get source nautilus # get nautilus source
cd nautilus-2.32.2.1
patch -p1 < ../sftp_default.patch # apply patch to set sftp (SSH) to default protocol
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b # build .deb files
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i *.deb # install .deb files
```

Where sftp_default.patch contains:

```
diff -ruN nautilus-2.32.2.1.a/src/nautilus-connect-server-dialog.c nautilus-2.32.2.1.b/src/nautilus-connect-server-dialog.c
--- nautilus-2.32.2.1.a/src/nautilus-connect-server-dialog.c    2011-08-21 16:00:30.720119356 +1200
+++ nautilus-2.32.2.1.b/src/nautilus-connect-server-dialog.c    2011-08-21 16:00:36.250910768 +1200
@@ -96,9 +96,9 @@
 /* Remember to fill in descriptions below */
 static struct MethodInfo methods[] = {
    /* FIXME: we need to alias ssh to sftp */
-   { "sftp",  SHOW_PORT | SHOW_USER },
+   { "sftp",  DEFAULT_METHOD | SHOW_PORT | SHOW_USER },
    { "ftp",  SHOW_PORT | SHOW_USER },
-   { "ftp",  DEFAULT_METHOD | IS_ANONYMOUS | SHOW_PORT},
+   { "ftp",  IS_ANONYMOUS | SHOW_PORT},
    { "smb",  SHOW_SHARE | SHOW_USER | SHOW_DOMAIN },
    { "dav",  SHOW_PORT | SHOW_USER },
    /* FIXME: hrm, shouldn't it work? */
```

To check to see if I could restore Nautilus to the default Ubuntu package, I used:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus
```

Works like charm, thanks again Pavlos G.

I found http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=101097 to be helpful with recompiling the package.

Comment: glad to hear that ;-)